# monacaとニフクラ mobile backendで403エラーになってしまい登録できなくなってしまいます。

Tags: javascript, monaca

**目標**
テーブルから値を取得→表示→別のテーブルにその値を登録ということを不定期な時間繰り返したい

**出てしまうエラー**
エラーコード：403 Forbidden
内容：POST https://mbaas.api.nifcloud.com/2013-09-01/classes/timeline 403 (Forbidden)

**試してみたこと**
1.setする内容を減らしてみる。
2.await/asyncを付けた場合と消した場合でどちらかがエラーが出ないなどあるかの確認。
3.登録できるまでTL関数を呼び出してみる。

結果、全てダメでした。

**備考**
asyncとawaitに関しては他のサイトで聞き、その通りに入れたので間違いはないと思います(まだ勉強中でその辺りは未学習のため)。
DevToolのネットワークタブで確認したところ、TimeLineという項目は弐つありました。
片方はエラーなしでもう片方はエラーとなっていました。
要求方法はOPTIONS(エラーなし)とPOST(エラー有り)となっていたのでこの辺りが原因かとも思いましたが、同じ関数を呼び出しているのに最初の一回だけ成功する理由にはなりません。
ご教授いただければ幸いです。

**問題のソースコード**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, viewport-fit=cover">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
  <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/onsenui/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsenui/css/onsenui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsenui/css/onsen-css-components.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  
</head>
<body>
  <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="center" id="toolbar-title">
      </div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <ons-tabbar position="auto">
      <ons-tab label="TOP" page="tab1.html" active>
      </ons-tab>
      <ons-tab label="DM" page="tab2.html">
      </ons-tab>
    </ons-tabbar>
  </ons-page>

  <ons-template id="tab1.html">
    <ons-page id="first-page">
      <span id="contents"></span>
    </ons-page>
  </ons-template>

  <ons-template id="tab2.html">
    <ons-page id="second-page">
      <span id="name_list"></span>
    </ons-page>
  </ons-template>

  <script>
    
    const applicationKey = '正しいアプリケーションキー';
    const clientKey = '正しいクライアントキー';
    const ncmb = new NCMB(applicationKey, clientKey);
    
    const Task = ncmb.DataStore("chat");
    const task = new Task();
    let array = [];

    const Task_2 = ncmb.DataStore("Ids");
    const task_2 = new Task_2();

    const Dm_name = ncmb.DataStore("dm");
    const dm_name = new Dm_name();

    const Time_Line = ncmb.DataStore("timeline");
    const time_line = new Time_Line;

    let date = new Date();
    let y = date.getFullYear();
    let m = date.getMonth() + 1;
    let d = date.getDate();
    let h = date.getHours()
    let minute = date.getMinutes();
    let num = (Math.floor(Math.random()*3) + 2) * 60 * 1000;
    let num_tweet = 1;
    let ids_name = {};
    let name_real = {};
    let html;
    //エラーになった値を入れる変数群
    let err_name = [];
    let err_id = [];
    let err_contents = [];
    let err_num = 0;
    let err_dt = [];
    let err_uniqueId = [];
    //ユニークキー
    let name_twitter, id, contents, dt, unique_id;

    ons.ready(function() {
      console.log("Onsen UI is ready!");
    });
    
  
    document.addEventListener('show', function(event) {
      let page = event.target;
      let titleElement = document.querySelector('#toolbar-title');
      if (page.matches('#first-page')) {
        titleElement.innerHTML = 'TOP<img src="img/reload.png" class="reload" onclick="reload()">';
      } else if (page.matches('#second-page')) {
        titleElement.innerHTML = 'DM<img src="img/reload.png" class="reload" onclick="reload()">';
      }
    });
    
    const event = window.cordova ? 'deviceready' : 'DOMContentLoaded';
    
    //numミリ秒に一回処理を走らせる
    document.addEventListener(event, function() {
      html = "";
      //タイムラインが存在しているかどうかの確認
      Time_Line.fetchAll()
      .then(function(results){
        //存在していた場合
        if(results.length > 0){
          for(let i=0; i<results.length; i++){
            let tl = results[i];
            unique_id = tl["unique_key"];
            //htmlが空白であれば=で入れる
            if(html == ""){
              if(tl["nice"] == "true"){
                html = temp_nice(tl["name"], tl["id"], tl["contents"], tl["date"]);
              }else{
                html = temp(tl["name"], tl["id"], tl["contents"], tl["date"]);
              }
              
              document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML = html;
            }else{//空白でなければ前にくっつけていく
            if(tl["nice"] == "true"){
              html = temp_nice(tl["name"], tl["id"], tl["contents"], tl["date"]) + html;
            }else{
              html = temp(tl["name"], tl["id"], tl["contents"], tl["date"]) + html;
            }
              
              
              document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML = html;
            }
            num++;
          }
        }
      })
      .catch(function(err){
        console.log("【エラー：" + err.code + "】"  + err);
      });

        //dm_title();
        setInterval("tweet()", num);

    });

    if (ons.platform.isIPhoneX()) {
      document.documentElement.setAttribute('onsflag-iphonex-portrait', '');
      document.documentElement.setAttribute('onsflag-iphonex-landscape', '');
    }

    //ハートのクリックイベント
    function heart(event){
      let e = event || window.event;
      let elem = e.target || e.srcElement;
      let elemId = elem.id;
      
      document.getElementById(elemId).classList.toggle("active_icon");
      html = document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML;

      let tf = document.getElementById(elemId).classList.contains("active_icon");
      
      unique_key = elemId.replace("heart_", "");
      
      //検索
      Time_Line.equalTo("unique_key",unique_key).fetch()
      .then(function(object){
        if(tf == true){
          object.set("nice", "true");
          return object.update();
        }else{
          object.set("nice", "false");
          return object.update();
        }
      })
      .then(function(result){
        console.log("成功！");
      })
      .catch(function(error){
        console.log("【取得or更新失敗】" + error.message);
        document.getElementById(elemId).classList.toggle("active_icon");
      });
     
    }
    
    //リロード
    async function reload(){
      document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML = html;
      //err_*の配列の一つのサイズを取得
      let err_len = err_name.length;
      console.log("エラーになった数：" + err_len);
      let err_i, err_c, err_n, err_d, err_ui;
      for(let i=0; i<err_len; i++){
        //変数にi番目の値を入れる
        err_i = err_id[i];
        err_c = err_contents[i];
        err_n = err_name[i];
        err_d = err_dt[i];
        err_ui = err_uniqueId[i];
        await console.debug("【" + err_n + ", " + err_i + ", " + err_c + ", " + err_d + ", " + err_ui + "】");
      
        //セットする
        try {
        const nemui = await time_line
          .set("name", err_n)
          .set("date", err_d)
          .set("unique_key", err_ui)
          .set("contents", err_c)
          .save();
        console.log("【成功】" + name_tweet + ", " + id + ", " + dt + ", " + contents);
        // 保存後の処理
        num_tweet++;
        unque_id = new Date().getTime().toString();
        } catch (err) {
        console.log("【エラー:" + err.code + "】" + err);
        TL(err_n, err_d, err_c, err_ui, err_i);
        }
      }
    }

    //呼び出し
    function tweet(){
      date = new Date();
      y = date.getFullYear();
      m = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
      d = date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
      h = date.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0');
      minute = date.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
      let h_moji;
      dt = y + "-" + m + "-" + d + " " + h + ":" + minute;
      if(html == ""){
        name_twitter = "テスト";
        id = "test_plactice";
        contents = "このツイートは練習です！";
        html = temp("テスト", "test_plactice", "このツイートは練習です！", dt);
        TL(name_tweet, dt, contents, unique_id, id);
      }else{
        Task.fetchAll()
      .then(function(results){

          //ランダムに値を取得
          let rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*results.length);
          let moji = results[rand];
          unique_id = new Date().getTime().toString();
          contents = moji["contents"];
          Task_2.equalTo("name", moji["name"])
          .fetch()
          .then(function(result){
            id = result["id"];
            name_tweet = result["name_twitter"];
            h_moji = temp(name_tweet, id, contents, dt);
            console.log(name_tweet + ", " + id + ", " + contents);
            html = temp(name_tweet, id, contents, dt) + html;
          TL(name_tweet, dt, contents, unique_id, id);
      });
        
        
        document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML = html;
        num = Math.floor(Math.random()*3) + 2;
        num = num * 60 * 1000;
      });
      }

      /*
      time_line.set("name", name_tweet)
        .set("id", id)
        .set("date", dt)
        .set("unique_key", unique_id)
        .set("contents", contents)
        .save()
        .then(function(nemui){
          console.log("【成功】" + name_tweet + ", " + id + ", " + dt + ", " + contents);
          // 保存後の処理
          num_tweet++;
          unque_id = new Date().getTime().toString();
        })
        .catch(function(err){
          console.log("エラーです！");
        });
        */
    }
    function temp(name, id, contents, date){
      let moji;
      moji = "<div class='row' id = '" + unique_id + "'><span class='name'>" + name + "</span><span class='id'>" + id + "</span><span class='date_tweet'>" + date + "</span><div class='contents'>" + contents + "</div><img class='icon heart' id='heart_" + unique_id + "' src='img/nice.png' onClick='heart()'><img class='icon reply' id='reply' src='img/reply.png'></div>";
      
      return moji;

    }
    
    function temp_nice(name, id, contents, date){
      let moji;
      moji = "<div class='row'><span class='name'>" + name + "</span><span class='id'>" + id + "</span><span class='date_tweet'>" + date + "</span><div class='contents'>" + contents + "</div><img class='icon heart active_icon' id='heart_" + unique_id + "' src='img/nice.png' onClick='heart()'><img class='icon reply' id='reply' src='img/reply.png'></div>";
      
      return moji;

    }
    
    async function TL(name_tweet, dt, contents, unique_id, id){
      time_line
        .set("name", name_tweet)
        .set("date", dt)
        .set("contents", contents)
        .set("id", id)
        .set("unique_key", unique_id);
      try {
        const gameScore = await time_line.save();
        console.log("【保存成功！】ID：" + id + ", name：" + name_tweet + ", date：" + dt + ", contents：" + contents);
        unque_id = new Date().getTime().toString();
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("【エラー：" + err.code + "】" + err);
        console.log("【エラーになったコンテンツ】 " + name_tweet + ", " + contents + ", " + dt);
        err_contents[err_num] = contents;
        err_dt[err_num] = dt;
        err_name[err_num] = name_tweet;
        err_id[err_num] = id;
        err_uniqueId[err_num] = unique_id;
        err_num++;
      }
    }
    
    function registry_timeline(){

    }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました。

`const` を`let` にし、`set` を呼び出しているところで上書きすることでエラーが出なくなりました。

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, viewport-fit=cover">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
  <script src="components/loader.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/onsenui/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/loader.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsenui/css/onsenui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsenui/css/onsen-css-components.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  
</head>
<body>
  <ons-page>
    <ons-toolbar>
      <div class="center" id="toolbar-title">
      </div>
    </ons-toolbar>
    <ons-tabbar position="auto">
      <ons-tab label="TOP" page="tab1.html" active>
      </ons-tab>
      <ons-tab label="DM" page="tab2.html">
      </ons-tab>
    </ons-tabbar>
  </ons-page>

  <ons-template id="tab1.html">
    <ons-page id="first-page">
      <span id="contents"></span>
    </ons-page>
  </ons-template>

  <ons-template id="tab2.html">
    <ons-page id="second-page">
      <span id="name_list"></span>
    </ons-page>
  </ons-template>

  <script>
    
    let applicationKey = 'アプリケーションキー';
    let clientKey = 'クライアントキー';
    let ncmb = new NCMB(applicationKey, clientKey);
    
    let Task = ncmb.DataStore("chat");
    let task = new Task();
    let array = [];

    let Task_2 = ncmb.DataStore("Ids");
    let task_2 = new Task_2();

    let Dm_name = ncmb.DataStore("dm");
    let dm_name = new Dm_name();

    let Time_Line = ncmb.DataStore("timeline");
    let time_line = new Time_Line;

    let date = new Date();
    let y = date.getFullYear();
    let m = date.getMonth() + 1;
    let d = date.getDate();
    let h = date.getHours()
    let minute = date.getMinutes();
    let num = (Math.floor(Math.random()*3) + 2) * 60 * 1000;
    let num_tweet = 1;
    let ids_name = {};
    let name_real = {};
    let html;
    //エラーになった値を入れる変数群
    let err_name = [];
    let err_id = [];
    let err_contents = [];
    let err_num = 0;
    let err_dt = [];
    let err_uniqueId = [];
    //ユニークキー
    let name_twitter, id, contents, dt, unique_id;

    ons.ready(function() {
      console.log("Onsen UI is ready!");
    });
    
  
    document.addEventListener('show', function(event) {
      let page = event.target;
      let titleElement = document.querySelector('#toolbar-title');
      if (page.matches('#first-page')) {
        titleElement.innerHTML = 'TOP<img src="img/reload.png" class="reload" onclick="reload()">';
      } else if (page.matches('#second-page')) {
        titleElement.innerHTML = 'DM<img src="img/reload.png" class="reload" onclick="reload()">';
      }
    });
    
    let event = window.cordova ? 'deviceready' : 'DOMContentLoaded';
    
    //numミリ秒に一回処理を走らせる
    document.addEventListener(event, function() {
      html = "";
      //タイムラインが存在しているかどうかの確認
      Time_Line.fetchAll()
      .then(function(results){
        //存在していた場合
        if(results.length > 0){
          for(let i=0; i<results.length; i++){
            let tl = results[i];
            unique_id = tl["unique_key"];
            //htmlが空白であれば=で入れる
            if(html == ""){
              if(tl["nice"] == "true"){
                html = temp_nice(tl["name"], tl["id"], tl["contents"], tl["date"]);
              }else{
                html = temp(tl["name"], tl["id"], tl["contents"], tl["date"]);
              }
              
              document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML = html;
            }else{//空白でなければ前にくっつけていく
            if(tl["nice"] == "true"){
              html = temp_nice(tl["name"], tl["id"], tl["contents"], tl["date"]) + html;
            }else{
              html = temp(tl["name"], tl["id"], tl["contents"], tl["date"]) + html;
            }
              
              
              document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML = html;
            }
            num++;
          }
        }
      })
      .catch(function(err){
        console.log("【エラー：" + err.code + "】"  + err);
      });

        //dm_title();
        setInterval("tweet()", num);

    });

    if (ons.platform.isIPhoneX()) {
      document.documentElement.setAttribute('onsflag-iphonex-portrait', '');
      document.documentElement.setAttribute('onsflag-iphonex-landscape', '');
    }

    //ハートのクリックイベント
    function heart(event){
      let e = event || window.event;
      let elem = e.target || e.srcElement;
      let elemId = elem.id;
      
      document.getElementById(elemId).classList.toggle("active_icon");
      html = document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML;

      let tf = document.getElementById(elemId).classList.contains("active_icon");
      
      unique_key = elemId.replace("heart_", "");
      
      //検索
      Time_Line.equalTo("unique_key",unique_key).fetch()
      .then(function(object){
        if(tf == true){
          object.set("nice", "true");
          return object.update();
        }else{
          object.set("nice", "false");
          return object.update();
        }
      })
      .then(function(result){
        console.log("成功！");
      })
      .catch(function(error){
        console.log("【取得or更新失敗】" + error.message);
        document.getElementById(elemId).classList.toggle("active_icon");
      });
     
    }
    
    //リロード
    async function reload(){
      document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML = html;
      //err_*の配列の一つのサイズを取得
      let err_len = err_name.length;
      console.log("エラーになった数：" + err_len);
      let err_i, err_c, err_n, err_d, err_ui;
      for(let i=0; i<err_len; i++){
        //変数にi番目の値を入れる
        err_i = err_id[i];
        err_c = err_contents[i];
        err_n = err_name[i];
        err_d = err_dt[i];
        err_ui = err_uniqueId[i];
        await console.debug("【" + err_n + ", " + err_i + ", " + err_c + ", " + err_d + ", " + err_ui + "】");
      
        //セットする
        try {
        let nemui = await time_line
          .set("name", err_n)
          .set("date", err_d)
          .set("unique_key", err_ui)
          .set("contents", err_c)
          .save();
        console.log("【成功】" + name_tweet + ", " + id + ", " + dt + ", " + contents);
        // 保存後の処理
        num_tweet++;
        unque_id = new Date().getTime().toString();
        } catch (err) {
        console.log("【エラー:" + err.code + "】" + err);
        TL(err_n, err_d, err_c, err_ui, err_i);
        }
      }
    }

    //呼び出し
    function tweet(){
      date = new Date();
      y = date.getFullYear();
      m = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0');
      d = date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
      h = date.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0');
      minute = date.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0');
      let h_moji;
      dt = y + "-" + m + "-" + d + " " + h + ":" + minute;
      if(html == ""){
        name_twitter = "テスト";
        id = "test_plactice";
        contents = "このツイートは練習です！";
        html = temp("テスト", "test_plactice", "このツイートは練習です！", dt);
        TL(name_tweet, dt, contents, unique_id, id);
      }else{
        Task.fetchAll()
      .then(function(results){

          //ランダムに値を取得
          let rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*results.length);
          let moji = results[rand];
          unique_id = new Date().getTime().toString();
          contents = moji["contents"];
          Task_2.equalTo("name", moji["name"])
          .fetch()
          .then(function(result){
            id = result["id"];
            name_tweet = result["name_twitter"];
            h_moji = temp(name_tweet, id, contents, dt);
            console.log(name_tweet + ", " + id + ", " + contents);
            html = temp(name_tweet, id, contents, dt) + html;
            
          TL(name_tweet, dt, contents, unique_id, id);
      });
        
        
        document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML = html;
        num = Math.floor(Math.random()*3) + 2;
        num = num * 60 * 1000;
        document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML = html;
      });
      reload();
      }

      /*
      time_line.set("name", name_tweet)
        .set("id", id)
        .set("date", dt)
        .set("unique_key", unique_id)
        .set("contents", contents)
        .save()
        .then(function(nemui){
          console.log("【成功】" + name_tweet + ", " + id + ", " + dt + ", " + contents);
          // 保存後の処理
          num_tweet++;
          unque_id = new Date().getTime().toString();
        })
        .catch(function(err){
          console.log("エラーです！");
        });
        */
        console.log("【HTML】" + html);
        document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML = html;
    }
    function temp(name, id, contents, date){
      let moji;
      moji = "<div class='row' id = '" + unique_id + "'><span class='name'>" + name + "</span><span class='id'>" + id + "</span><span class='date_tweet'>" + date + "</span><div class='contents'>" + contents + "</div><img class='icon heart' id='heart_" + unique_id + "' src='img/nice.png' onClick='heart()'><img class='icon reply' id='reply' src='img/reply.png'></div>";
      
      return moji;

    }
    
    function temp_nice(name, id, contents, date){
      let moji;
      moji = "<div class='row'><span class='name'>" + name + "</span><span class='id'>" + id + "</span><span class='date_tweet'>" + date + "</span><div class='contents'>" + contents + "</div><img class='icon heart active_icon' id='heart_" + unique_id + "' src='img/nice.png' onClick='heart()'><img class='icon reply' id='reply' src='img/reply.png'></div>";
      
      return moji;

    }
    
    async function TL(name_tweet, dt, contents, unique_id, id){
        Task = ncmb.DataStore("chat");
        task = new Task();
        array = [];

        Task_2 = ncmb.DataStore("Ids");
        task_2 = new Task_2();

        Dm_name = ncmb.DataStore("dm");
        dm_name = new Dm_name();

        Time_Line = ncmb.DataStore("timeline");
        time_line = new Time_Line;

      time_line
        .set("name", name_tweet)
        .set("date", dt)
        .set("contents", contents)
        .set("id", id)
        .set("unique_key", unique_id);
      try {
        let gameScore = await time_line.save();
        console.log("【保存成功！】ID：" + id + ", name：" + name_tweet + ", date：" + dt + ", contents：" + contents);
        unque_id = new Date().getTime().toString();
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("【エラー：" + err.code + "】" + err);
        console.log("【エラーになったコンテンツ】 " + name_tweet + ", " + contents + ", " + dt);
        err_contents[err_num] = contents;
        err_dt[err_num] = dt;
        err_name[err_num] = name_tweet;
        err_id[err_num] = id;
        err_uniqueId[err_num] = unique_id;
        err_num++;
      }
    }
    
    function registry_timeline(){

    }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```